# d3 choropleth map is extremely small

Tags: d3.js, topojson

I am trying to draw an svg map from a topojson file located [here](https://rawcdn.githack.com/jasonicarter/toronto-geojson/0fb40bd54333bc3d397a26cf4f68abb1b6d94188/toronto_topo.json). When I run the code below, I see a small red collection of `g` elements that is that map, but I'm not sure how to make it larger. I've tried doing `projection.scale(100)` but that does not work.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/6dh1tqkp/2/) is a fiddle.

```html
<svg width=500 height=500></svg>
```

```js
async function run() {
  const res = await fetch(
    "https://rawcdn.githack.com/jasonicarter/toronto-geojson/0fb40bd54333bc3d397a26cf4f68abb1b6d94188/toronto_topo.json"
  );
  const jsondata = await res.json();

  const width = 500;
  const height = 500;


  const neighbourhoods = topojson.feature(jsondata, jsondata.objects.toronto);
    
  const projection = d3.geoAlbers().translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    
  const svg = d3.select("svg")

  svg
    .append("g")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(neighbourhoods.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.geoPath().projection(projection))
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("stroke", "white");
    
  console.log("done")
}

run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, you have to use the `scale` and the `translate` properties to scale / center your map.
But `d3.geoProjection` also provides some convenience functions such as [fitExtent](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#projection_fitExtent) and [fitSize](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#projection_fitSize) in order to fit the projection on one specific GeoJSON feature object.

As your dataset is containing many features, I propose to use [topojson.mesh](https://github.com/topojson/topojson-client/blob/master/README.md#mesh) to obtain a unique object representing your whole dataset (as a mesh) to use its extent with the `fitSize` method of the projection to scale your map :

```
const neighbourhoods = topojson.feature(jsondata, jsondata.objects.toronto);
const mesh = topojson.mesh(jsondata, jsondata.objects.toronto);

const projection = d3.geoAlbers()
  .fitSize([width, height], mesh);
    
const svg = d3.select("svg")

svg
  .append('g')
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(neighbourhoods.features)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", d3.geoPath().projection(projection))
  .attr("fill", "red")
  .attr("stroke", "white");
```

Which (after adding a border on the svg element) gives the following :

[image: result-image]

If you wanted to fit the extent using a some padding (lets say 20px) you could have use the following :

```
const projection = d3.geoAlbers()
  .fitExtent([[20, 20], [width - 20, height - 20]], mesh);
```